# Getting an exception Error processing GroovyPageView: could not initialize a collection

Tags: oracle, hibernate, grails, groovy

Below are my two domain classes

class Line_Of_Business{
    static hasMany = [lp:Lob_Position_Type_Mapping]

```
String LOB_NAME;
String ACTIVE_FG;
String LOB_USER_CREATED;
Date   LOB_DT_CREATED;
String LOB_USER_MODIFIED;
Date   LOB_DT_MODIFIED;

//tells grails the PK
static mapping = {      
    version false
    columns { id column:'LOB_ID' }
    id generator:'sequence', params:[sequence:'LOB_ID_SN']
}   

static constraints = { 
    LOB_NAME(nullable:false,blank:false,maxSize:100)
    ACTIVE_FG(nullable:true,blank:false,maxSize:1)
    LOB_USER_CREATED(nullable:true,blank:true)
    LOB_DT_CREATED(nullable:true,blank:true)
    LOB_USER_MODIFIED(nullable:true,blank:false)
    LOB_DT_MODIFIED(nullable:true,blank:false)
}
```

}

import java.util.Date;

class Lob_Position_Type_Mapping {

```
Integer LOB_ID;
Integer CUST_POSITION_TYPES_ID;
String LPM_USER_CREATED;
Date   LPM_DT_CREATED;
String LPM_USER_MODIFIED;
Date   LPM_DT_MODIFIED;

static mapping = {
    version false
    columns { id column:'LPM_ID' }
    id generator:'sequence', params:[sequence:'LPM_ID_SN']
}

static constraints = {
}
```

}

LOB list is coming properly. When I click on each LOB getting below exception

org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.exceptions.GroovyPagesException: Error processing GroovyPageView: could not initialize a collection: [Line_Of_Business.lp#1]

```
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:183)

at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:95)

at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)

at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)

at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not initialize a collection: [Line_Of_Business.lp#1]

```
at gsp_ADMIN_MODULE_line_Of_Businessshow_gsp$_run_closure2.doCall(gsp_ADMIN_MODULE_line_Of_Businessshow_gsp.groovy:89)

at gsp_ADMIN_MODULE_line_Of_Businessshow_gsp$_run_closure2.doCall(gsp_ADMIN_MODULE_line_Of_Businessshow_gsp.groovy)

at gsp_ADMIN_MODULE_line_Of_Businessshow_gsp.run(gsp_ADMIN_MODULE_line_Of_Businessshow_gsp.groovy:110)

... 6 more
```

Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00972: identifier is too long

```
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:951)

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513)

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227)

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:208)

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:886)

at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1175)

at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1296)

at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3613)

at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3657)

at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1495)

at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeQuery(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:342)

... 9 more
```

I'm new to grails.
Can some one please check and let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: The ORA-00972 is the part that needs investigating, https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora00972.php, it's not obvious from above as your identifiers appear to be < 30 chars but something isn't at runtime, try adding `logSql: true` to the relevant dataSource in application.yml & check the generated queries

Comment: Yeah I found a query which is giving problem. But don't how it is getting generated. This is the query that is causing problem. select
        lptm0_.line_of_business_lptm_id as line1_0_,
        lptm0_.lob_position_type_mapping_id as lob2_0_ 
    from
        line_of_business_lob_position_type_mapping lptm0_ 
    where
        lptm0_.line_of_business_lptm_id=? . Don't know how this concatenation of two tables are happening.

Comment: So the problem is probably this `line_of_business_lob_position_type_mapping` which Grails/Hibernate thinks is the name of one of your tables. This seems to be the query generated when you click on an individual item in the list view to go to the show view.

Comment: If it's not obvious why this is happening I'd start by removing the underscores from your class and field names & use camel case.